# Using Generalized Rice's Theorem to Prove Decidability

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability, semi-decidability, rice-theorem

I have a Turing Machine M with a binary alphabet {1,2} that accepts a language L(M) that has infinitely many strings that start with 1 and finitely many strings that start with 2. I'm trying to determine if L(M) is decidable, semi-decidable (computably enumerable) or undecidable.

Using Rice's Theorem, I believe I can prove that L(M) is not decidable:

> P is the property of a language where the language has infinitely many strings that start with one symbol and finitely many strings that start with another symbol. P is non-trivial and is a property of languages of TMs. Therefore, according to Rice's Theorem, M = {⟨M⟩∣L(M) has has infinitely many strings that start with 1 and finitely many strings that start with 2 and Σ = {1,2}} is undecidable.

But I'm struggling to prove whether it's semi-decidable or completely undecidable. [This post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2293/can-the-encodings-set-of-a-non-trivial-class-of-languages-which-contains-the-emp) mentions using an Generalized Rice's Theorem to prove that a language is recursively enumerable (aka semi-decidable) but I'm having trouble understanding their approach.

Can anyone shed some light on this approach and/or if I'm heading down the right path? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have a Turing machine $M$. In fact, you're interested in the language $L$ of (descriptions of) Turing machines $M$ that accept infinitely many strings starting with 1 and finitely many strings starting with 2. This is *not* what you wrote. You're not after $L(M)$. You're after $L$.

Comment: Have you tried applying the generalized Rice's theorem? Did you get stuck? The generalized Rice's theorem is not so complicated, I suggest you try it out.

Comment: Also, Rice's theorem cannot be used to prove decidability (at least not directly). It shows that the given language is undecidable or even not r.e.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to ignore the second half of your post, and answer the question that appears at the first half. If this is not what you meant - post another question or edit as necessary.

Given a machine $M$ we define $L(M)$ to be the language recognized by that machine. In other words, $L(M)$ is the set of all the words $w\in \Sigma^*$ such that $M$ accepts $w$.

Thus, by its definition $L(M)$ is at least semi-decidable (because $M$ is accepting it!!)

To clarify whether $L(M)$ is decidable or semi-decidable(but not fully decidable), we need more information on $M$.

For instance, it can be that $M$ is the trivial machine that immediately go to the accepting state. In that case $L(M)=\Sigma^*$ (all the possible words), and $L(M)$ is decidable.

On the other hand it can be that $M$ does the following:

```
1. it ignores the first symbol of the input
2. it runs HP on the rest of the input
```

where HP is the machine that accepts the Halting Problem language. It is not too difficult to see that in this case $L(M)$ cannot be fully decidable (or otherwise the halting problem will be decidable), but, as said above, it is semi-decidable by definition (that is, it is in $RE\setminus R$).

Now, if you don't care about a **specific** machine $M$, but instead about *all* the machines that accept infinitely many words that begin with 1 and infinitely many words that begin with 2, the language that contain all such machines cannot be decidable due to Rice's theorem.

Just to be clear on the statement: let $S \subset RE$ be all the languages that contain infinitely many words that start with 1 as well as infinitely words that start with 2, then

$$L_S = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \in S \}$$ cannot be decidable, $L_S\notin R$. Note that $L_S$ contains all the (encodings of) machines that satisfy the property $S$  defined in your question.