# Isn't the given characterisation of recursively enumerable subsets of the class of all recursively enumerable languages?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, church-turing-thesis

$S$ is a subset of the class of all recursively enumerable languages over some finite symbols then $S$ is recursively enumerable iff

1. If $L$ is in $S$ and $L'$ is a language such that $L ⊆ L'$ and $L'$ is recursively enumerable, then $L'$ is in $S$
2. If $L$ is an infinite language in $S$, then there exists at least one finite subset of $L$ that is in $S$
3. The set of all finite languages in $S$ is enumerable, i.e. a Turing machine can list all the finite languages in $S$

Source of the statement: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2322 and some online notes

Isn't the 3rd one contradictory to the 1st one?

Comment: No, because you are misreading the third condition. It doesn't say that $S$ contains all the finite r.e. languages. It says that those finite r.e. languages that happen to be in $S$ are r.e.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not contradictory. Both conditions are *positive* in the sense that they "put things in $S$", so they cannot be at odds with each other.

There is an equivalent formulation of $S$: there is an r.e. set $B$ of finite languages such that
$$S = \{L \mid \text{$L$ is r.e. and $\exists L_0 \in B \,.\, L_0 \subseteq L$}\}.$$
In words: $S$ is generated by an r.e. set of finite language $B$ in the following way: $S$ contains precisely all r.e. languages which contain an element of $B$.

Comment: So, whats the 3rd statement mean exactly? I still didn't get.

Comment: It says that there is a machine $M$ which enumerates $\{L \in S \mid \text{$L$ is finite}\}$. Is that clear?

Comment: Then it means {$L\in S∣L$ is finite} is r.e, but by 1st statement r.e set should contains some infinite sets also, thats what I want to clarify

Comment: The first condition does *not* say that. For instance $S$ could be empty. The first condition says that **if** $L \in S$ and $L \subseteq L'$ **then** $L' \in S$. So yes, *if* $S$ contains a finite language, *then* it also contains a lot of infinite languages.

Comment: Still, there is no contradiction. Are you using the word "contradiction" to mean "this looks strange to me"? Because that's not how it's used.

Comment: So, every r.e $S$ which is nonempty contains an infinite language. But by 3. "The set of all finite languages in $S$ is enumerable", consider the set of all finite languages in $S$($S$ is r.e) which itself is a r.e set, then it doesn't contain an infinite set.

Comment: Precisely, if $S$ is an r.e. set of r.e. langauges, then $\{L \in S \mid \text{$L$ is finite}\}$ is not an r.e. set of r.e. languages, according to the definition (unless $S = \emptyset$). What is the problem? Note that $S$ itself is not a language, it is a set of languages. There are deeper reasons why the definition is given in the way it is given.

Comment: "Note that S itself is not a language, it is a set of languages" ? Its a language, contains encoding of TMs as per the definition I know https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85322/discussion-between-saravanan-and-andrej-bauer

Comment: No, $S$ is not a language. It is a set of languages because nowhere did we say that the languages are encoded using TMs. This is why we have a special definition what it means for $S$ to be  an "r.e. set of languages". Note that "$S$ is an r.e. set of r.e. languages" is *different* from stating that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid \exists L \in S \,.\, \text{$n$ encodes $L$}\}$ is r.e.

Comment: Ok, you incorrectly transcribed the definition from https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/2322 by filiing to use encodings of languages. I give up.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer I think that linked answer itself has flaws which lead to this misunderstanding, let alone the "language/machine" notation which adds up to the confusion. See my answer to the same question here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3063866/300521. I also commented on the linked answer.

Comment: I gave up a while ago.

Comment: @Andrej Bauer btw, is the mentioned alternative form in your answer exactly equivalent of the original Rice-Shapiro formulation? I've seen it in the Rogers' book, but its converse case also applies, i.e. all sets of the mentioned form are c.e., which is not correct for the theorem stated in the compactness+upward-closure form, so I guess.